# Can't use Win+E / Mod4+E shortcut under Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout, mate, ubuntu-mate

I am having problems in **Ubuntu-MATE 18.04** to use the <kbd>Windows</kbd>-<kbd>E</kbd> shortcut alias <kbd>Mod4</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> to start caja (the standard “File Explorer” of MATE).

- **this worked flawlessly on multiple Ubuntu-MATE 16.x machines.**
- **also: <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>Mod4</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> does work(!)**

### Who or what captures my <kbd>Win</kbd>-<kbd>E</kbd> under 18.x?

I don't see any occupancy in the normal keyboard shortcuts list...

(PS: If you wonder, why I have to use parameters with caja, that's [explained here](https://github.com/mate-desktop/caja/issues/390))

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Well, it's all related to the „ibus input method“ and the „GTK Emoji Selector“ as far as I could figure out. Being in a terminal (or any other gtk app, e.g. pluma) pressing ctrl-E, `:-)`, enter gets you an actual unicode smiley,…  fancy, but obstructing in applications requiring this shortcut.

Most advice on the net highlights to use `ibus-setup` and remove or change the keyboard shortcut. As it turns out, the ibus package isn't even installed at all in Ubuntu MATE 18.04. Also, setting the general language input method from `ibus` to `none` in general language settings is not helping. It already is set to `none`.

So yes, it's a bit of a miracle where all of this got hardwired into Ubuntu 18…

**The only thing that does work [I found on superuser](https://superuser.com/a/1421979/75914):**

```
$> gnome-language-selector

set "Keyboard input method system: XIM"
(apply system-wide is not necessary.)

$> mate-session-save --logout   (or sudo reboot, as you wish)
```